# Start a interactive login shell from Node.js

Tags: node.js, shell, authentication, terminal, interactive

I need to open **interactive login shell** from my electron application, after reading some other topic I found that we can set `options.stdio` to `inherit` from spawn method to open interactive shell
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#optionsstdio

but I can't found anything about login shell. I also tried adding `options.shell` like this (I'm just trying)

```
{ shell: 'C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe --login' }
```

Is this possible to do?